# Swift - assign local variables based on function parameters

Tags: swift, syntax, constructor, initialization, keyword

I have an initialization pattern for an immutable class initializer, where all of the parameters are passed in at creation time.
I am assigning all of the internal variables based on this - so there is a lot of boiler plate and I tend to forget things and make errors.
I am curious if there is a way to assign the internal properties in the function declaration. Is there a key word for that (like `inout`)?

For instance now:

```
private var param1
private var param2
private var param3
...
private var paramN

init(param1, param2, param3, ..., paramN) {
  self.param1 = param1
  self.param2 = param2
  self.param3 = param3
  ...
  self.paramN = paramN
}
```

...would be much cleaner and less error prone, if there was a way to have the function param variable be the internal instance variable:

```
init(self.param1, self.param2, ...)
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, the initializer function you want is only generated when no other initializer is present, and even this is restricted only to structs.

I'd recommend filing a bug, seems like a somewhat useful feature. Keep in mind however that initializers cannot be referenced like normal functions (i.e. you cannot store them in variables).

Comment: Only structs have a default constructor (if no init method is provided), not classes.

Comment: @MartinR: Darn it, you're right. I'll update my answer.